# Need to understand the event-triggering in this WPF program . .

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to learn SharpDX by using an example program (http://sharpdxwpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SharpDX.WPF.sln) ... it creates a quadrant of 4 shaded triangles using 4 different approaches and it just runs by itself redrawing the graphics. It runscontinuously and seems to be event-driven because I continuously hit breakpoints in event handlers (see below)  but I don't understand what triggers these events.
In the XAML it has . . .

```
  xmlns:dxc="clr-namespace:SharpDX.WPF;assembly=SharpDX.WPF"
```

. . .

```
<dxc:DXElement Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="dxview10"/>
<Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="img"/>       
<dxc:DXElement Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="dxview11"/>
<dxc:DXElement Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="dxview2d"/>
```

. . . 
Where DXElement's declaration and constructor look like this
 . . .

```
public class DXElement : FrameworkElement, INotifyPropertyChanged

public DXElement()      
{         
    base.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;         
    m_renderTimer = new Stopwatch();         
    m_surface = new DXImageSource();          
    m_surface.IsFrontBufferAvailableChanged += delegate         
    {                
        UpdateReallyLoopRendering();
        if (!m_isReallyLoopRendering && m_surface.IsFrontBufferAvailable)
            Render();
        };
        IsVisibleChanged += delegate { UpdateReallyLoopRendering(); };
    }
```

The rest of DXElement is just brief event handlers. Here's one example:

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
{
    dc.DrawImage(Surface, new Rect(RenderSize));
}
```

Notice the "override".   I'm assuming that one of the parent classes of DXElement ( FrameworkElement or INotifyPropertyChanged ) are already listening for these events.  But what's **triggering** these events? (e.g., *OnRender()*, *OnLoopRendering()*, etc) They seem to be the engine that runs the program.   How can I track what causes events like this to fire in a WPF program?
If I set a breakpoint at them I see them getting hit, but they're called from the framwework, e.g.,

> SharpDX.WPF.dll!SharpDX.WPF.DXElement.OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext
>   dc) Line 153 C#
>   PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(System.Windows.Rect
>   finalRect) Unknown
>   PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Grid.ArrangeOverride(System.Windows.Size
>   arrangeSize) Unknown
>   PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(System.Windows.Rect
>   finalRect) Unknown
>   PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(System.Windows.Rect
>   finalRect) Unknown
>   PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Helper.ArrangeElementWithSingleChild(System.Windows.UIElement
>   element, System.Windows.Size arrangeSize) Unknown
>   PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.ArrangeOverride(System.Windows.Size
>   arrangeSize) Unknown

... so I don't understand what the program is doing to make these events happen.  How do I figure that out?

Answer (score 5):

They use per-frame rendering using global `CompositionTarget.Rendering` event. It is get called once per frame, for all subscribers. You can read more details about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748838%28v=vs.100%29.aspx.

At DXElement source code you see Renderer dependency property. In property changed handler for this property you will see how they subscribe to mentioned `CompositionTarget.Rendering` event if some conditions match (control is visible, not in design mode and so on). They also start `Stopwatch` to measure how much time has passed since the beginning, then render the frame.

As for OnRender handler you mentioned. This one is called during layout pass (when parent controls decide how to lay out their children) under some conditions. It is called once when DXElement is first rendered, then it is called when you for example resize DXElement, or call `InvalidateVisual` on it. But it is *not* called when those triangles change color in your example - this is done using `CompositionTarget.Rendering` event.

So short answer to your question would be - all events used in your example are triggered by WPF rendering system.

Answer (score 1):

A rough guess is that it is calling [InvalidateVisual()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatevisual(v=vs.110).aspx) from within a recurrent timer, which at some point will invoke [OnRender()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.onrender(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I did a find-in-files search in the entire solution for "InvalidateVisual" and got 0 hits.   So unless that's being called from something else in the framework that's invoked indirectly from the program then that doesn't seem to be it.   This is why I'm looking for some way to track events in a WPF program, to see what's firing them.   How do I do that?

Comment: You can use https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ but it won't return such low-level events, maybe XAMLSpy (untested). Or if you have Reshaper you could find usages of that method with Shift+F12 key.

Comment: I tried XAMLSpy but I couldn't get it to find my program.   I don't have Resharper (I assume that's what you meant by "Reshaper")